# Is a US visa valid without an entry stamp?

Tags: air-travel, transit, uk, london

I would be travelling to the US with H4 visa (first time travelling to the US) through London HT. I came across in the gov.uk site that a Valid US visa holder does not require a transit visa.

"You are exempt from needing a transit visa if you are travelling to the US, Canada, Australia or New Zealand and have a valid visa for this country"

Is an H4 visa (without any prior port of entry stamping)considered a valid US visa? Do I have to get a Transit visa?

Comment: Can you enter the US with it or not?

Comment: If H4 is stamped yes.  I-797(Notice of Action) or a similar form isn't really valid at the border.

Comment: The sole purpose of a U.S. visa is for entry to the U.S. Therefore, it would be quite useless if it were not valid prior to entry.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The visa sticker need not have an entry stamp.

The other answer appears to be confused because some people use the term "visa stamp" to refer to the visa sticker, and "visa stamping" to refer to the insertion of the visa sticker into the passport.  However, it is obvious from the question that you are asking about the inked entry stamp, which, when a visa is first used, is placed so that it is partly on the visa sticker and partly on the passport page.

Comment: Notably, the United States _does not_ refer to the visa foil as a "stamp" in any official communications anywhere, ever.